# Nextjs 13 useSearchParams returns null when using the 'as' prop in <Link />

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to add a page id to each page in Nextjs 13 using the App Router. So I have created a custom link and I am using the `as` value to mask the url.

```
let pid = 0 // this will dynamically increase for every page but I will spare you all of that code
<Link href={`/?pid=${pid}`} as="/">
  Home
</Link>
```

So then in previous versions with the Pages Router you could do the following and get the `pid` just fine. I just tested this and it works fine.

```
const router = useRouter()
console.log(router.query)

// result { pid: 1}
// url show in browser http://localhost:3000
```

As you can see in the above example I am able to get the `pid` query params and not display them in the address bar. Now using the `useSearchParams()` hook with the App Router it just returns null every time. Did they remove this functionality from Nextjs 13? I don't see any documentation on this when looking at either the Router docs or the Link docs for either the Pages/App respectively. [Router Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) - [Link Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link).

I am trying to keep track of page specific data and it seems like Nextjs is trying as hard as they can to make this difficult.

**-- a bit of a rant feel free to ignore --**

You can't use the `window.history.state` because they just override this wiping anything you save away. There are many cases where you need this and there is a good reason why this is a feature in modern browsers. Most notably is scroll restoration with custom scrollbars. Taking away this functionality seems intrusive. In previous versions they would save a page key in the `window.history.state` so you could at least use that but now they have taken that away. So I could just leave the pid in the url but that would make a whole new set of challenges and it obviously doesn't look as good. I know this last paragraph was a bit of a rant but I have been frustrated Nextjs's attitude when it comes to window history for a long time and I am about to just go into the source code and change it so they just copy over existing window history state instead of completely overriding it so I can add a page id to the window history.

Comment: Have you tried `const pathname = usePathname();`?

Comment: @ahsan `usePathname()` doesn't return the search params it returns the pathname. So it would just return `/`

Comment: I can only assert, that using `useRouter` still works. Not sure why you have to use `useSearchParams´, which is probably for another use case?

Comment: It looks like `next/link` strips query parameters in this case, and the browser navigates to the page without any query parameters. Maybe it's bug in `next/link`?

Comment: @madflow unfortunately you cannot use the Pages router in the new App directory. You have to use their App Router.

Comment: @IgorDanchenko Ya I'm just going to chalk it up to Nextjs 13 being in it's infancy. I think I am just going to hijack the window.history.pushState and replaceState with a proxy and push in my own page key when they are called. Its a bit hacky but I'm out of ideas other than that.

Comment: Why this question still no body answered?